# Change detector is waiting to complete API service call

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have one parent child relationship in component.
In Parent component I am setting the variable which is @Input property in child. In next statement i am making service request to API. But the change detector is detecting changes after service response

Parent Component:

```
this.subscription = this.service.metadataSource.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        // I want ngOnChange should called from here
        **debugger(debug1)**
        this.activeSignId = this.editSignId; // here im setting the @input prop of Child
        forkJoin(
          this.service.getSignListDetails(this.customerSignTypeId),
          this.service.getSignAttributesByCustomerId(this.customerId, this.customerSignTypeId),
        ).subscribe(data => {...
          **debugger(debug2)**
          // But ngOnChange is called from here(After response of api)
        })
      }
    })
```

Child Component:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    **debugger(debug3)**
    if (changes.activeSignId && changes["activeSignId"].isFirstChange()) {
      this.makeCustomStoreList();
   }
}
```

Currently debuggers are executing in following sequence

1. debug1
2. debug2
3. debug3

But I need to execute it like

1. debug1
2. debug3
3. debug2

May be it is due to single thread nature of Javascript. But how can i achieve it in another way.

**Updated**

```
this.subscription = this.service.metadataSource
    .pipe(tap(_ => this.activeSignId = this.editSignId))
    .subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        forkJoin(
          this.service.getSignListDetails(this.customerSignTypeId),
          this.service.getSignAttributesByCustomerId(this.customerId, this.customerSignTypeId),
        ).subscribe(data => {
          // other things
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: `this.activeSignId = this.editSignId;` <- i am not sure if this will trigger changes actually

Answer (score 2):

Try to not use nested subscriptions as much as possible. Instead you could use RxJS operators and functions to refine the data stream.

Try the following

```js
this.subscription = this.service.metadataSource.pipe(
  tap(_ => this.activeSignId = this.editSignId),
  switchMap(data =>
    iif(() => 
      data,
      forkJoin(
        this.service.getSignListDetails(this.customerSignTypeId),
        this.service.getSignAttributesByCustomerId(this.customerId, this.customerSignTypeId),
      )
    )
  )
).subscribe(
  data => {
    ...
  },
  err => { }
);
```

I've used [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator to perform a side-effect (assign `this.activeSignId` here) and [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to switch the observable if the output from source observable is valid. The validity is checked using RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) function.

This also ensures that `this.activeSignId` is assigned before the `forkJoin` is triggered.

Comment: I dont think this is an answer for him, he is looking to trigger the changes not the way to wrap rxjs operators.

Comment: And yet this answer provides both the solutions. It avoids nested subscriptions and ensures the `this.activeSignId` is assigned before the `forkJoin` is even evaluated. In which order do you think the operators are evaluated?

Comment: please mention that in the answer, i also needed the solution.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelD for suggestion, this.activeSignId is assigned but still the changes are not detected by child component.

Comment: @HPSingh: Are they still detected after the completion of the `forkJoin` or is the `ngOnChanges()` never triggered?

Comment: it's detected after forkJoin.

Comment: Are you assigning another value to `activeSignId` in the subscription callbacks?

Comment: No, I am assigning it only in tap operator. For now I have not used switchMap, I am updating the question with code, I have.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelD, Its ngOnChanges() not triggering...

Comment: @HPSingh: Again, try not to use nested subscriptions, you end up with subscriptions and in your case if you are using `this.subscription` variable to unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy` hook, then it's use is completely undercut because there's an additional subscription.

Comment: As for the `ngOnChanges()` issue, if it's never triggered, then you need to show how the variables `this.activeSignId` and `this.editSignId` is defined. The `ngOnChanges()` will only be triggered if the underlying reference to the `@Input` variables are modified. So for eg. if you were to assign the same object to them, the reference wouldn't change and it won't be triggered.